# Обновление Android-приложения без Play Market

Tags: android

Пример: распространяю свое приложение на Android со своего сайта, пользователи установили его. Аккаунта разработчика в Google Market нет. Если я сделаю новую версию приложения - как мне обновлять уже установленное приложение? Как сделать так, чтобы при выходе новой версии - устаревшая версия (которая установлена у пользователя) перестала работать и писало уведомление: "Скачайте новую версию". Либо подскажите альтернативные способы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечаю сам. Нашел то, что искал здесь: https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/279553/

В этой статье описано, как небольшим куском кода добавить в приложение контроль версий.

Answer (score 6):

Добавьте в приложение контроль версии при старте.

Приложение при запуске(или по расписанию) делает запрос к серверу, получает номер текущей актуальной версии, сравнивает с установленной и действует по обстоятельствам